# How do I solve this error on expo: Error ENOENT: No such file or directory?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am creating a mobile application on expo go. Recently I started receiving the following error when I ran expo start. I have updated expo, npm, deleted and reinstalled my node modules, clear cache with expo start -c. None of them seem to fix the error. I have also made sure to check all the import statements to verify that they exist.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\alterfix\OneDrive\Desktop\Eater\http:\192.168.1.11:19000\src%5CApp.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
at getCodeFrame (C:\Users\alterfix\OneDrive\Desktop\Eater\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:949:18)
at Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\alterfix\OneDrive\Desktop\Eater\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1022:22)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at Server._processRequest (C:\Users\alterfix\OneDrive\Desktop\Eater\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:429:7) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\Users\alterfix\OneDrive\Desktop\Eater\http:\192.168.1.11:19000\src%5CApp.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}

Any solutions?

Comment: You cannot use `readFile` to send a web request!